# Get variable contents from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to parse javascript variable from strings.
Something like that,

```
var string = "<script>window.arr=[1, 2.0, false]</script>";
```

Is there any way I can get the contents of a single variable from here?

```
 //something like
 function getVarContent(variable, string){
    var re = new RegExp('');
    return eval(re.exec(string))
}
getVarContent('arr', string)
```

Comment: Do you trust the contents of those strings? Would it be feasible to just execute it?

Comment: No, I dont want to execute all of it.Simply get parts of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe overkill for a simple use with a known string, but if you need to support general parsing, you can use the `DOMParser` if your environment supports it. (See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for reasons why regex may not be the answer)

[insert all the usual caveats about `eval()ing` strings]

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var string = "<script>window.arr=[1, 2.0, false]<\/script>";
var doc = parser.parseFromString(string, "text/html");

var script = doc.querySelector('script')
eval(script.innerHTML)
console.log(window.arr)
```

Comment: I really dont want to execute the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

you should put

```
var string = "<script>window.arr=[1, 2.0, false]</script>";
//only valid letters
var getVar = string.match(/\[[[0-9,.a-z ]+]/g);
console.log(getVar);
var array = JSON.parse(getVar);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: This works the example above, but I need a general solution to be able to get specific variables.